# php embed image broken

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hi I'm trying to embed an image in an email and here is my php code:

```
$mail1->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 
$mail1->isSMTP();                                     
$mail1->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
$mail1->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail1->Username = 'email@gmail.com';                
$mail1->Password = 'password';                           
$mail1->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                   
$mail1->Port = 587;
$mail1->setFrom('auto-reply@email.ca', '123');                  
$mail1->addAddress('email@gmail.com');     
$mail1->isHTML(true);                                 
$mail1->Subject = 'Thanks For Reaching us!';
$mail1->Body    = '
       <p> This is a test picture  <img src="img/logo.png"/>  </p>              
         ' ;

$mail1->send();
exit;
```

When I run this code on my localhost, the email shows text but with a broken sign of a image, and I've tried all the way including

```
$mail1->AddEmbeddedImage('img\logo.png', "two", "logo.png");
```

however, it doesn't show the image at all, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: 2nd argument is the cid, which you dont use, and you probably need the full server path for the image

Comment: ^ When you 'open source' or 'view link' of the image this should be evident.

Answer (score 0):

This will fail because it's a relative path, and emails have no base URL to be relative to (and that's not how you target an embedded image), so it won't work.

```
$mail1->Body = '<p>This is a test picture <img src="img/logo.png"/></p>';
```

Do this instead:

```
$mail1->Body = '<p>This is a test picture <img src="cid:two"/></p>';
```

Then it will work with:

```
$mail1->AddEmbeddedImage('img\logo.png', "two", "logo.png");
```

because the `cid` value matches. It's worth using absolute paths to be sure of where you're loading from, and you can check the return value of the call to be sure that it's able to read the file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me, I tried the way you said, but the picture just didn't show at all

Comment: Did you check the return value and the path?